# Windows is not genuine slmgr -rearm error

Tags: windows-7, sysprep, unattended

I am working on building a custom image of widows 7 in audit mode. I run into an error with my unatttend.xml file when i reboot the computer out of audit mode and i get an error that windows could not parse my unattend.xml file.

I notice that this only happens after i get the windows is not genuine message while im in audit mode. I tried using slmgr -rearm but whenever i try i get errors about not having permission to run that command.

Is there another way to get rid of the windows is not genuine message?
or could the problem be something with my unattend.xml file? I can  post it if that helps.

Comment: i want to add that i know the problem im having is due to the windows is not genuine message because i tried making an image and running sysprep before getting the windows message and i did not get any errors about my unattend file.

Comment: whats the generic key?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this problem. There is an update KB971033. Skip this update and it will not check if the copy of windows is genuine.

Comment: If you're using unattended.xml, there should be a generic key there somewhere.